# Document is undefined using jQuery in nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a project, the project was a WordPress template and it's converted to Nextjs application.

They used jQuery and gsap for animations. The problem is I got 500 error for document in inspect network.

The real problem is the animation doesn't affect in first load of the page I must navigate to another page and return to the previous page then the animations are applied.

- jQuery package version: 3.7.1
- Nextjs version: 14.1.0
- React version: 18
- react-dom version: 18

and I got an error in the terminal for using jQuery:

> node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js (24:26) @ document  ⨯ TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
> at **webpack_require** (E:\Projects\nextjs\webmehrtech.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> at eval (./src/utils/buttonAnimation.js:5:64)
> at (ssr)/./src/utils/buttonAnimation.js (E:\Projects\nextjs\webmehrtech.next\server\app\page.js:617:1)
> at **webpack_require** (E:\Projects\nextjs\webmehrtech.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> at eval (./src/app/template.tsx:12:80)
> at (ssr)/./src/app/template.tsx (E:\Projects\nextjs\webmehrtech.next\server\app\page.js:276:1)
> at **webpack_require** (E:\Projects\nextjs\webmehrtech.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> null

`buttonAnimation` file in `util` folder:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import jQuery from "jquery";

export function buttonAnimation() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    (function ($) {
      "use strict";

      $(".tp-hover-btn").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

        $(this).find(".tp-btn-circle-dot").css({
          top: y,
          left: x,
        });
      });

      $(".tp-hover-btn").on("mouseout", function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

        $(this).find(".tp-btn-circle-dot").css({
          top: y,
          left: x,
        });
      });

      var hoverBtns = gsap.utils.toArray(".tp-hover-btn-wrapper");

      const hoverBtnItem = gsap.utils.toArray(".tp-hover-btn-item");
      hoverBtns.forEach((btn, i) => {
        $(btn).mousemove(function (e) {
          callParallax(e);
        });
        function callParallax(e) {
          parallaxIt(e, hoverBtnItem[i], 80);
        }

        function parallaxIt(e, target, movement) {
          var $this = $(btn);
          var relX = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
          var relY = e.pageY - $this.offset().top;

          gsap.to(target, 0.5, {
            x: ((relX - $this.width() / 2) / $this.width()) * movement,
            y: ((relY - $this.height() / 2) / $this.height()) * movement,
            ease: Power2.easeOut,
          });
        }
        $(btn).mouseleave(function (e) {
          gsap.to(hoverBtnItem[i], 0.5, {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power2.easeOut,
          });
        });
      });

      if ($(".tp-btn-trigger").length > 0) {
        gsap.set(".tp-btn-bounce", { y: -150, opacity: 0 });
        const mybtn = gsap.utils.toArray(".tp-btn-bounce");
        mybtn.forEach((btn) => {
          var $this = $(btn);
          gsap.to(btn, {
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: $this.closest(".tp-btn-trigger"),
              start: "top center",
              markers: false,
            },
            duration: 1.5,
            delay: 1,
            ease: "bounce.out",
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
          });
        });
      }

      if ($(".tp-btn-trigger-2").length > 0) {
        gsap.set(".tp-btn-bounce-2", { y: -100, opacity: 0 });
        const mybtn = gsap.utils.toArray(".tp-btn-bounce-2");
        mybtn.forEach((btn) => {
          var $this = $(btn);
          gsap.to(btn, {
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: $this.closest(".tp-btn-trigger-2"),
              start: "bottom bottom",
              markers: false,
            },
            duration: 1,
            ease: "bounce.out",
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
          });
        });
      }

      if ($(".tp-btn-trigger-3").length > 0) {
        gsap.set(".tp-btn-bounce-3", { y: -100, opacity: 0 });
        var mybtn = gsap.utils.toArray(".tp-btn-bounce-3");
        mybtn.forEach((btn) => {
          var $this = $(btn);
          gsap.to(btn, {
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: $this.closest(".tp-btn-trigger-3"),
              start: "-20% 20%",
              markers: false,
            },
            duration: 1,
            delay: 1.2,
            ease: "bounce.out",
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
          });
        });
      }
    })(jQuery);
  }
}
```

my template.tsx file code:

```
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

import { buttonAnimation } from "@/utils/buttonAnimation";

const RootTemplate = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      buttonAnimation();
    }
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default RootTemplate;
```

console network screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think that jQuery tries to access `window.document` when you import it, so wrapping the code in `typeof window` doesn't help, it's too late. Can you use dynamic `import('jquery')`?

Comment: I tried it but I got error of undefined JQurey

Comment: mabe `window = global = this` fix